# vs2008, open current file in source control explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

Can I jump to source control explorer, and navigate to current open solution?

I already mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to `View.TfsSourceControlExplorer`, but I would like it to automatically navigate to the current selected file in the solution explorer.